# My else statement in an else if tree isn't printing

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class youalwaystwo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String sentence;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a sentence.");
    sentence = keyboard.nextLine();
    {
    if (sentence.charAt(sentence.length()-1) == '?' ) if (sentence.length( ) %2 == 0)
          System.out.println("Yes.");
        else if (sentence.charAt(sentence.length()-1) == '?' ) if (sentence.length( ) %1 == 0)
          System.out.println("No.");
        else if (sentence.charAt(sentence.length()-1) == '!' )
          System.out.println("Wow.");
        else
          System.out.println("You always say \"" + sentence + "\".");
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is when I enter a sentence without a ? or ! nothing gets printed.

Comment: Note that you have two `if` in one line, and without brackets, the `else` will always be an else to the last if. Maybe this is the problem. Try fixing your indentation and/or adding brackets to see the true structure of that "if-else-tree". Also, try to replace that second `if` in the same line with `&&` in the first if`s condition.

Comment: You should really indent your code better. And also respect code conventions. For instance class names are always with the first letter capitalized.

Comment: That is one heck of a logic mess over there.

Answer (score 4):

I have formatted your code and added brackets, it should now be fairly obvious what is happening:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentence;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a sentence.");
    sentence = keyboard.nextLine();
    if (sentence.charAt(sentence.length() - 1) == '?') {
        if (sentence.length() % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Yes.");
        } else if (sentence.charAt(sentence.length() - 1) == '?') {
            if (sentence.length() % 1 == 0) {
                System.out.println("No.");
            } else if (sentence.charAt(sentence.length() - 1) == '!') {
                System.out.println("Wow.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You always say \"" + sentence + "\".");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i.e. you have one big `if` that checks for the `?` at the end - if there isn't one nothing happens.

A lesson to take away from this; **always** use `{}` (when you get to know Java a little better there are exceptions to this rule, but right now **always**).

Comment: Adding brackets for each of the `if` and `else` blocks is the right thing to do but the placement of the last `else` is always debatable.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ - this is what my IDE suggested, so this is now the compiler would evaluate it...

Comment: Exactly my point. It may seem right to you, me and the IDE but the OP may have a different logic. That's why I said it is debatable :) But your answer to use brackets is the right one!

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ agreed, what the OP intended is certainly debatable.

Comment: Completely agree with Boris -- it's better to use `{}` due to a huge number of benefits (one of them being readability for others).

Answer (score 1):

You have a mess of badly indented `if` statements, so it is very hard to see what happens. Let's indent it properly and add `{` and `}` to make it clear what the structure of your code is.

```
if (sentence.charAt(sentence.length()-1) == '?' ) {
    if (sentence.length( ) %2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Yes.");
    }
    else if (sentence.charAt(sentence.length()-1) == '?' ) {
        if (sentence.length( ) %1 == 0) {
            System.out.println("No.");
        }
        else if (sentence.charAt(sentence.length()-1) == '!' ) {
            System.out.println("Wow.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You always say \"" + sentence + "\".");
        }
    }
}
```

Now you see what happens if the sentence does not have a `?` at the end: the expression for the first `if` will evaluate to `false` and everything else will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `if` statements should be like this :

```
  if (sentence.charAt(sentence.length() - 1) == '?') {///// for ? 
     if (sentence.length() % 2 == 0) {
         System.out.println("Yes.");
      } else if (sentence.length() % 1 == 0) {
          System.out.println("No.");
        }
   } else if (sentence.charAt(sentence.length() - 1) == '!') {/// for !
          System.out.println("Wow.");
    } else {
          System.out.println("You always say \"" + sentence + "\".");/// for anything else without ? or !
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (sentence.charAt(sentence.length()-1) == '?' ) if (sentence.length( ) %2 == 0)
    System.out.println("Yes.");
else if (sentence.charAt(sentence.length()-1) == '?' ) if (sentence.length( ) %1 == 0)
```

to

```
if (sentence.charAt(sentence.length()-1) == '?' && sentence.length( ) %2 == 0)
    System.out.println("Yes.");
else if (sentence.charAt(sentence.length()-1) == '?' && sentence.length( ) %1 == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the actual problem has been caused by the very confusing layout of the if statement ladder.

Simply format the code to avoid such problems. Many of the recent Java editors have the "format source" feature that can do this automatically. I am sure be it properly aligned, it would be easy to see any issues. The exact coding style used is not important here, just use any.